# How to get list of supported currencies in flutter_stripe?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

Is it possible to get a list of currencies, supported by stripe, in `flutter_stripe`?

Comment: You need to make a request using your secret key to retrieve the country_spec object : https://stripe.com/docs/api/country_specs/object. This isn't inherently supported by flutter_stripe which is used to collect payment method details and confirm payment but you can make a request to your backend to retrieve/return this information.

Comment: @alex Thanks. As far as I understand - it is dangerous to send secret key from mobile app. I use `firestore-stripe-payments` firestore extention as stripe backend to avoid sending secret key. Is there any chance this extention provides a list of currencies in some way?

Comment: you should never store the secret key in your mobile app. Your mobile app would make a request to your server, your server subsequently makes the request using the secret key to Stripe. No, that extension doesn't provide a list of currencies. You need to implement the code to make that request.

Comment: @alex you should post all those as answers